# Spring - ConversionService no @Autowired because of ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i've found a problem when using the Spring `ConversionService` (first I thought this was related to my test, but this was my error, it happens always). I try to create it via...

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.mybasepacke"})
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean   
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService(ApplicationContext context) {

        ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();

        Map<String, MyConverter> converters = context.getBeansOfType(MyConverter.class);
        factory.setConverters(new HashSet<>(converters.values()));
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory;
    }
}
```

This way, I expect to be able to simply create `Converter`s (`MyConverter` is just a marker interface that extends Spring's `Converter`) like this...

```
@Component
public class ExampleConverter implements MyConverter<Something, SomethingElse> {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;
... }
```

Spring should find all the `MyConverter`s, add them all to the `ConversionService` (Factory) and I'll be able to use them... Theoretically. In reality, this happens:

1. `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` gets initialized.
2. It optionally depends on a `ConversionService`.
3. Spring finds my `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` definition and starts it.
4. Unfortunately, `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` is created BEFORE the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is registered. So all of its dependencies are NOT autowired. Which leads to all my converters not being autowired.

Has anyone an idea how to prevent this behavior? Or do I have to get rid of ConversionService since it doesn't seem to be able to use Converters with autowired fields?

Comment: AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor order is Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 2; and ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor order is Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1; Higher values can be interpreted as lower priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't name your `ConversionService` `conversionService`, [check the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-conversion) that basically explains what you found out yourself.

```
@Bean   
public ConversionService myConversionService() {
  // your setup 
}
```

This is going to register a `myConversionService` (notice the method name) that will not be eagerly loaded by the configuration stuff. If you need some converters to coerce value from configuration (as defined in the doc), consider marking those converters with `ConfigurationPropertiesBinding`:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
// This can't autowire things either ...
public class ExampleConverter implements MyConverter<Something, SomethingElse> { ... }
```

Comment: This saved me an hour of debugging why the conversionService's @Autowired properties were not injected. +1